# Ajax call locally in jQueryMobile and Phonegap, JSON objects

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have very simple jQueryMobile application. I want to submit a form and to call ajax. On my desktop PC this works fine and looks like this:

**[application on my PC](http://imageshack.com/a/img856/3561/4svn.png)**

When i press the button "Save" the text below appers. The HTML code for the interface is in the script accountAdd.html. At my PC It works as expected, but i need this app for my mobile device. Here is the screenshot from my device when i try to do the same thing that is showed at the first figure.

**[application on my mobile device](http://imageshack.com/a/img809/5087/7xlx.jpg)**

So here is the part of the script that calls ajax.

**accountAdd.html**

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         $(document).on('submit', '#formDetails', function() { 
         var theName = $("#accountName").val();
         if($('#accountName').val().length > 0) {                   
              $.ajax({
                   url: 'accountAdd.php',
                   data: $('#formDetails').serialize(),
                   type: 'post',                   
                   dataType: 'json',
                   timeout: 5000,   
                   success: function (result, status) {                             
                                $("#resultLog").html("accountName: " + result.accountName);                             
                            },
                   error: function (request,error) {                                
                                alert('Network error has occurred please try again! Error: ' + error);                              
                            }
              });                  
         } else {
             alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
         }           
         return false; 
         });    
    });
</script>
.
.
.
HTML code
```

Here is my other script that contains code that is executed in back-end.

**accountAdd.php**

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

$return['accountName'] = $_POST['accountName'];
$return['accountType'] = $_POST['accountType'];
$return['accountBalance'] = $_POST['accountBalance'];
$return['accountDate'] = $_POST['accountDate'];

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

So the ajax call on my mobile device is not working as expected and as you can see at the second figure is giving **parseerror**. The code is completely the same at both devices. I'am converting the scripts with phonegap. I think that the problem is related with JSON objects (I think that ajax call in phonegap need to pass JSON obejects but I'm not sure). I need help, how to modify the code, so that can work at the PC and at my mobile device at the same time.

Comment: how is configured access origin in config.xml? (it's set to * in cordova 3.3 but with older versions the default setting restricted ajax calls to localhost)

Comment: I'm using PhoneGap cloud for conversion, so I don't have config.xml file, but I'am using the latest version of PhoneGap 3.3.0.

Comment: You're supposed to use a config.xml file to configure your app with phonegap build, so inside you should have a access origin line.

Comment: I have tried what you said, so my config.xml file looks like [this one](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml) (of course i have changed personal info) but it's not working again. I also tried to change PhoneGap version from 3.1.0 to 3.3.0 but again I got the parserror on my device :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have `<access origin="*"/>` so it is not a CORS issue.

I think maybe your problem is that you do not set the datatype to json in your php but expect it in the javascript side. Try adding the following line in your php file :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**Edit**

---

I see the url to your php uses local path (should have noticed earlier but didn't know if you removed the server address on purpose), so it seems you put the .php files in the phonegap app.

That is not how it works. Either you need to do things locally and you do it in javascript, or you want to communicate with a server and you

- do not put any php page in the www folder of your local page
- provide the url of your server to each ajax calls.

Comment: call your php from a browser with developer tools and check the response in the network tab to see what's actually sent.

Comment: these are responses.. but I think that everything looks OK..

[headers](http://imageshack.com/a/img196/5012/94b8.png)
[headers when i click view source](http://imageshack.com/a/img138/1066/bb8d.png)
[Response tab in Network tab](http://imageshack.com/a/img812/5392/mhlh.png)

i forgot to mentioned that I have changed line: 
data: $('#formDetails').serialize(),
into line:
data: {accountName : theName},
because i want to be the simplest.. the other three attributes in accountAdd.php are commented for now

Comment: yep, seems correct. I don't think it will be usefull, but you can try to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');` in the php. If it still doesn't work, my last idea would be to remove the datatype from the ajax call and add an alert to see what you get for result in the success function.

Comment: As I look at your response capture, I see an empty line after the json response (line2). Maybe this causes the json corruption. Most probable cause would be you have a line break after `?>` in your php file. Try removing it.

Comment: I added the `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');` in the php, then i deleted break after `?>` but it didn't worked again. Then I remove dataType from ajax call and in chrome it was showing the correct result again, but on the device not. Now there was no parseerror at the device this time, the success function was executed.

Comment: But instead of value from the textbox is giving me value: undefined as you can see [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img802/998/u4wn.png). I  tried many combinations with _JSON.stringify_ but none gives me value from textbox above. When dateType is deleted, in Network tab, it gives me same response as before `{"accountName":"MyName"}`.

Comment: Try to watch the value of result in the result function, maybe you'll see why the response is not seen as json?

Comment: I tried to see content of many combinations, with [this code](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/801x163q90/580/otdi.png) and every line was returning value: undefined, except [JSON.stringify(result)](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/597x373q90/196/4jl3.png) and [result](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/597x373q90/191/vdlr.png) - they returned the content of my .php scrpt, as a string.

Comment: That's very strange, you get the content of the php source page and not the result of the php code execution like if php was not installed at all. Must be an issue with your http server and/or php config.

Comment: ok, I noticed the url to your php page : 'accountAdd.php', so you put your php page in the phonegap app? (see edit of my answer)

Comment: I want to do it locally, but how do you mean "in javascript"? Can you show me by example or give me link to some tutorial.. I can not find example anywhere and I'm new to this PhoneGap staffs. I really don't understand how to replace this php script with javascript :/

Comment: I mean you should not use an ajax call but instead call a javascript function or do what you need to do directly in the `if($('#accountName').val().length > 0) {`

Comment: so **THE SOLUTION** to this problem is actually to not use the ajax at all.. it's pure javascript code in `if($('#accountName').val().length > 0) {` block. Now the expected text is added on my PC and on my device. My goal was to learn ajax, but in the working solution there is no need of ajax after all. Tnx @QuickFix your answers will help to a lot of beginners like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config.xml file is in the same folder as your index.html file and then use the  (Or whatever domain you are on)